# Preserve whitespace between tags HTML

Tags: html, whitespace

I thought that html should make whitespaces between inline tags like `<a>one</a><a>two</a>` but it seems to work only when there is a line end between those tags. Please take a look at my example: http://jsfiddle.net/pwF7f/

So is it possible to have this whitespace even if the elements are on one line?

Comment: Do you mean you expect to see some space between the bits of text within the `a` elements? You need to insert some of you want to see a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML won't invent whitespace when it's not in the source.  You can always say:

```
 <a>one</a> <a>two</a>
```

if you want whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a whitespace however try `<a>one</a>&nbsp;<a>two</a>` or

```
<a>one</a>&nbsp;
<a>two</a>
```

If you want a non-breaking space

In my opinion it's more versatile than `<a>one</a> <a>two</a>`.

You can create e.g. something like this

```
<a>one</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a>two</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a>three</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a>four</a>
```

Compare with this code:

`<a>one</a> | <a>two</a> | <a>three</a> | <a>four</a>` |

There are other issues when using php echo in html. Then `&nbsp;` is a must.

Comment: ok thanks, however I was looking to something simple, because I dont' want to rewrite my xslt file :D, but It seems like I have no choice

Answer (score 0):

In addition to putting spaces or no-break spaces between elements, you can use CSS to create horizontal spacing, e.g. by setting `padding-right: 0.5em` on the first element.

There’s a reason why adjacent inline elements are treated as really adjacent, without any whitespace between them: there are situations where you really want that, as in *n*<sup>th</sup> (which should render as “nth” in a specific style, not as “n th”).

It is an old accessibility recommendation that there should be some non-whitespace characters between consecutive links. This is not quite as necessary as it was originally presented, but stull a good guideline – and surely there should be *at least* some whitespace.

Comment: I had this idea too, but it's impossible for me, because my html is generated via XSLT and there are tons of links in it and I need to have space only when two links are side by side

Comment: yes, using css is also a possibility, however, when css is missing it gets wrong. E.g. in RSS or on some weird or old browsers and devices.

Comment: @david, you can use e.g. `a + a { padding-left: 0.5em; }` to add left padding only when an `a` element is preceded by an `a` element. (The adjacent sibling selector `+` works on all modern browsers and even on IE 7.) But I agree with @Derfder that it is better to have a space (or another separator) in content